# Telegram Bot with Url InlineKeyboardButton for PHP

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

```
$data = [
    'text' => 'your message here',
    'chat_id' => '@channelname'
];

file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data));
```

I can send messages this way, but I want to dynamically put a button(link) in it. How can I do?

Comment: In what do you want to put a link?

Comment: @Tom Thank you, Problem Solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
<?php

    $token = '11345342......';
    $keyboard = json_encode([
        "inline_keyboard" => [
            [
                [
                    "text" => "Button 1",
                    "callback_data" => "1"
                ],
                [
                    "text" => "Button 2",
                    "callback_data" => "2"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $data = http_build_query([
        'text' => 'your message here',
        'chat_id' => '@channelname'
    ]);

    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?{$data}&reply_markup={$keyboard}";
    $res = @file_get_contents($url);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$token = "Your Token";
$chatID = "Your Chat iD";
$reply = "Message";


$keyboard = array(
    "inline_keyboard" => array(array(array("text" => "Your Buton Name", "url" => "Your Url")))
);

$keyboard = json_encode($keyboard, true);

$sendto = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$reply."&parse_mode=HTML&reply_markup=".$keyboard;

file_get_contents($sendto);
```